# Installing kde-wallet via Homebrew failed

Tags: homebrew

I am using a MacOS 14.2.1 Sonoma on an M2 Apple Silicon chip Macbook Air. I want to install the latest version of the kde-wallet through Homebrew, but am unable to succeed.

I ran the `brew upgrade kde-mac/kde/kf5-wallet` command, and expected it to take care of the rest. However, the following error message came up:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5I18n"
  (requested version 5.111.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5I18nConfig.cmake
    kf5i18n-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5I18n" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5I18n_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5I18n" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I couldn't find such a file on the device. I also don't know much about `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, so I don't know what I am supposed to do with this error message.